# Regular Expression Query

Tags: php, regex, pcre

My previous post was unclear, so i deleted it and here we go again.

in this link https://regex101.com/r/eLYvJM/2  I am trying to match only the words starting with `'` . I use this expression: `^'+\w+` but it only returns the first entry. I would like all of them starting with `'` . Note that the string `i'am` is undesirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `g` modifier to get multiple matches, and the multiline modifier `m`:

```
/^'+\w+/gm
```

The `m` modifier makes `^` match with the beginning of each line instead of the beginning of the whole text only.

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eLYvJM/4)

Comment: in java environment using the pattern class, would it be the same?

Comment: Why not... Did you try?

Comment: hmm yeah but it seems it doesn't do it for some reason.

Comment: Maybe ask a new question about that and provide your Java code with sample data.

Comment: it's just too big, I dont think anyone is gonna look it hehe. By the way, this: ^\'+\w+ would match the words i needs but for some reason it adds a --> '   into another word. Does this make any sense ?

Comment: Show an example in regex101.com?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eLYvJM/5  the word "gaffe" in java becomes " 'gaffe" for some reason.

Comment: I have no idea, how/what I am replacing?

Comment: Well, you tell me your string is changing and a `'` is added before `gaffe`. That can only happen when you create a new string, with `replace` or something. Really, you should post a new question to attract Java specialists, post your Java code and the data you put in and get out.